# How to ajax call for data to expand table row for more information

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

In the ajax call below, the variable shtml is empty. What is the correct way to assign the value to the variable? If I return it inside the success function I get a "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'show' of undefined" error. `row.child(moreinfo(row.data())).show();`

```js
function moreinfo(d) {
  var shtml = "";
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: Url + parseInt(d[1]),
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
      shtml = '<table" cellspacing="0" border="0"style="width: 100%;" >' +
        '<tr>' +
        '<td>Description:</td>' +
        '<td>' + data.description + '</td>' +
        '</tr>' +
        '</table>';

    },
    error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      alert(errorThrown.responseText);

    }
  });
  return shtml;


}

$('#Ptable tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function() {
  var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
  var row = table.row(tr);
  if (row.child.isShown()) {
    // This row is open - close 
    row.child.hide();
    tr.removeClass('shown');
  } else {
    // Open this row
    row.child(moreinfo(row.data())).show();
    tr.addClass('shown');
  }
});
```

Comment: you can do it with a [Promise](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_promise.asp) or as second parameter of the moreinfo function another function which accept the callback and do the further work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are working with `ajax` it will execute asynchronously. Thus on execution `$.ajax(`, it will not wait for response to come and go to next line which is `return shtml;` So, your `shtml` will always return `""`.

To solve your problem you can change your code as below.

1. Update parameters in `moreinfo` as `moreinfo(row, tr)`.
2. Get `d` value inside `moreinfo` with `let d = row.data();`.
3. Add `row.child(shtml).show();` & `tr.addClass('shown');` inside `success` callback from `$.ajax`.
4. Call `moreinfo(row, tr);` from `click`.

```js
// update function parameter
function moreinfo(row, tr) {
  // get data
  let d = row.data();

  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: Url + parseInt(d[1]),
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
      var shtml = '<table" cellspacing="0" border="0"style="width: 100%;" >' +
        '<tr>' +
        '<td>Description:</td>' +
        '<td>' + data.description + '</td>' +
        '</tr>' +
        '</table>';

      // Open this row
      // Add html to child
      row.child(shtml).show();
      tr.addClass('shown');

    },
    error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      alert(errorThrown.responseText);

    }
  });
}

$('#Ptable tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function() {
  var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
  var row = table.row(tr);
  if (row.child.isShown()) {
    // This row is open - close 
    row.child.hide();
    tr.removeClass('shown');
  } else {
    // Open this row
    moreinfo(row, tr);
  }
});
```